# How to get position for records grouped by one column sorted and sorted by another pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I have a very large DataFrame with ~100M rows that looks like this:

```
    query     score1    score2   key
0  query0  97.149704  1.317513  key1
1  query1  86.344880  1.337784  key2
2  query2  85.192480  1.312714  key3
3  query1  86.240326  1.317513  key4
4  query2  85.192480  1.312714  key5
...
```

I want to group the dataframe by `"query"` and then get the position of each row sorted by `"score1"` and `"score2"` (higher is better) so the output should look like this -

```
    query     score1    score2   key  pos1  pos2
0  query0  97.149704  1.317513  key1     0     0
1  query1  86.344880  1.237784  key2     0     1
2  query2  85.192480  1.312714  key3     1     0
3  query1  86.240326  1.317513  key4     1     0
4  query2  85.492410  1.212714  key5     0     1
```

Currently, I have a function that looks something like this:

```py
def func(query, df, score1=True):
    mini_df = df[df["query"] == query]
    mini_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    col_name = "pos_score2"
    if score1:
        col_name = "pos_score1"
    mini_df[col_name] = mini_df.index
    return mini_df
```

which I call from `main()`:

```py
p = Pool(cpu_count())
df_list = list(p.starmap(func, zip(queries, repeat(df))))
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

but it takes a long time. I am running this on machine with 96 CPUs Intel Xeon with 512G memory and it still takes more than 24 hrs. What would be a much faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Usually `pandas` is recommended for datasets smaller than a few Gb. You might want to look at libraries like `pyspark`/`koalas`, `dask`  or `vaex`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `rank`:

```
df[['pos1', 'pos2']] = (df.groupby('query')[['score1', 'score2']]
                          .rank(method='max', ascending=False)
                          .sub(1).astype(int))
print(df)

# Output
    query     score1    score2   key  pos1  pos2
0  query0  97.149704  1.317513  key1     0     0
1  query1  86.344880  1.237784  key2     0     1
2  query2  85.192480  1.312714  key3     1     0
3  query1  86.240326  1.317513  key4     1     0
4  query2  85.492410  1.212714  key5     0     1
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?